# iAd interstitial not working on device

Tags: swift, iad, interstitial, ios8.3

I am setting up my iAd interstitial like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812285/how-to-implement-interstitial-iads-in-swiftxcode-6-1).

When I run my app on simulator, the interstitial runs fine. But when I try it on my test device (iPhone 4s), I get this error:

```
Domain=ADErrorDomain 
Code=3 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable"
```

First I thought the iAd network may be down or something, but then I have tried this maybe like a 1000 times now over the last 2/3 weeks. Every single time, I get the exact same error on device, but it works just fine on the simulator. This is definitely not a coincidence, or Apple iAd network issue.

I searched online and found similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898902/iad-works-on-simulator-but-not-on-device), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579138/iad-banner-shows-test-ad-on-simulator-but-not-on-device), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798771/iads-showing-in-simulator-but-not-on-device) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232580/iad-appears-on-simulator-but-not-on-device), but none helped.
What am I doing wrong? Is this expected? Are test interstitial ads not served on test devices? iAd test banner ads are working fine on simulator and device. On my itunes-connect I have accepted all the agreements, etc so all is good over there. Also, on my test device the Settings > Debug > Fill Rate is set to 100%.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your preferred answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen occasionally, if it works in simulator then your ads will be just fine. You can make this happen less often by going into Settings -> Developer and changing this setting to 100%

[image: Developer settings]

Comment: That's the thing. It does not happen occasionally but happens every single time. As I said above, the test banner ads work fine. I've already set the fill rate to 100% which does apply to the banner ads just fine, but not the interstitial.

Comment: Yes, I do see the test ad on interstitial every time.

Comment: As i say in my answer, if it works on simulator it will work on device when they go live. Apple send different codes like this in development so that you can test your app with the error codes.

Comment: I hope that's the case! If there is no other satisfactory answer before the bounty ends, I'll accept yours.

Comment: Thank you. I recently made an app with iAds and I had the same issue. Then out of the blue whilst testing (no change in code at all) they began to work. So i really wouldn't worry about it, it will be fine in production. Although they can take a couple of days after the release of the app to begin working as they also get reviewed etc.

Comment: I am sorry, I had to travel outside the country for some emergency and was not able to give you the bounty. I do intend to release my app in this month. I will verify and accept your answer so that it might help some one else with the same issue.

Comment: The bounty will be released before then, well.. half of it